# Hibernate & EHCache performance issue

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I started experiencing performance issues when my application is starting up.
I have Hibernate 5.2.7 & EHCache 2.9.0.

As you can see from logs it takes 24 seconds to fully load Hibernate configuration:

```
19:29:16.446 INFO  - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
19:29:17.770 WARN  - HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [hibernate.ejb.interceptor], use [hibernate.session_factory.interceptor] instead
19:29:21.998 WARN  - No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/C:/Users/admin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.9.0/8a4f89d91daafb3994ed212201f935554a200b4b/ehcache-2.9.0.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
19:29:25.285 WARN  - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.Entity2]; using defaults.
19:29:28.652 WARN  - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.Entity1]; using defaults.
19:29:35.952 WARN  - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.Entity3]; using defaults.
19:29:35.958 WARN  - HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [org.Entity3]
19:29:40.486 INFO  - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

If I upgrade EHCache to 2.10.3 the issue still reproduces.

Answer (score 0):

You first thing to do seems to add an `ehcache.xml` file. Ideally with the correct caches configured. And see if it helps.

Also, I would suspect `updateCheck` which is a flag telling Ehcache to check if a new version is available. If you do not have access to internet, it can be super slow. So set it to false in your configuration.